# how to split data in xml file into different tablesbased on a tag in informatica data integration

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

for example:

```
<root>
    <item> 
       <itemno>1</itemno>
       <itemname>orders</itemname>
    </item>
     <book>
        <title>java</title>
        <author>over</<author>
     </book>
     <item>
          <itemno>2</itemno>
          <itemname>load</itemname>
       </item>
     </root>
```

the above is one XML files I want to load item tag to one table and book to another table

1)target table(item):
    item no item name
     1       orders
     2       load

2)target table(book):
     title   author
     java    over

I need this task in Informatica cloud data integration

thanks in advance

Comment: use a java transformation for a regular expression that extracts the tag, then use a router transformation to group the tags and send them to their respective targets :)

Comment: Use XMLParser to parse the data, then a Router to split them into target tables.